# HTML5 autocomplete feature not working in cordova

Tags: html, cordova, web-applications, autocomplete

I'm building an app with Cordova.
There is a form with one input (type text) and a submit button.
If I launch the app directly in a browser, [the HTML5 autocomplete feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-autocomplete) works as expected.
If I build the app via Cordova and test it on a physical device, autocomplete is not working.

Is there any reason to that ?

Comment: This is dependent on the OS/SDK version you are deploying to. Cordova has no control over UI layer, it is the native SDK webview and its compatibilities. Not all current SDK webviews have full HTML5 support.

Comment: Yes that was my first thought, but I'm testing on a nexus 5 / lollipop, so pretty much the latest version of webview. I also ran a test against the autocomplete feature via Modernizr that passed...

Comment: Also keep in mind that the SDK webview and the web browser on a device are not the same. In any case, cordova will have no effect on this as cordova only creates a basic native app with the main view as a native webview and has no control over the UI layer. I would look for HTML5 capabilities of the Lollipop SDK webview and see if you can find any issues there.

Comment: I'm observing the same problem on iOS 8.1. WKWebView (iOS) and WebView (Android) seems to both support HTML5 autocomplete. I'm searching a reference about HTML5 support in those webview, but can't find anything for now.

Comment: @inwpitrust @DawsonLoudon - has anyone been able to get `autocomplete` to work in Android/iOS cordova apps?  I am trying to streamline a signup form and want to auto populate the users name, email, phone number, etc but I can't seem to find any real references to standard HTML5 autocomplete - the only thing I am finding about autocomplete is references to auto-completing text search boxes based on a predefined set of words (or using an external source).  But I am referring to just standard HTML 5 `autocomplete='given-name'` and `autocomplete='email'` on `<input>` fields.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the time being appears to be: use a different webview such as Crosswalk. This is the only way that I could make it work in my app.

The ironic thing is if you search for autocomplete and phonegap or cordova, you will see many users around 2012 were trying to figure out how to disable it because they prefer the idea of the keyboard providing input suggestions.

Now there does not appear to be a way to get the default webview to support autocomplete even when desired.